# Duplicate class a.a found in modules

Tags: android

I have two libaries in my app authorizationsdk.aar and   iHealthSDK_2.9.6 and when run the app i got this error

Duplicate class a.a found in modules jetified-authorizationsdk-runtime (authorizationsdk.aar) and jetified-iHealthSDK_2.9.6 (iHealthSDK_2.9.6.jar)

Answer (score 0):

do you have two classes with a different name but with the same package in the two different libraries? If that is the case you need to change the package. Different libs should use different packages otherwise after the obfuscation the two classes will end up having the same name and package

`com.your.package.a.a`